# Android Notepadv3 tutorial - Is saveState() in onSaveInstanceState really necessary?

Tags: java, android, notepad

I am only a beginner to Android, but I have noticed a number of things that seem a little strange in the third notepad tutorial:

- The tutorial explicitly states that you need to call saveState from BOTH onSaveInstanceState and onPause. Is this really necessary? It seems to me from reading the process life-cycle documentation that onPause will always be called before the Activity is killed, regardless of whether it is done so by the system or the user. If this is the case, surely just calling saveState from onPause is sufficient?
- Calling populateFields() in both onResume and onCreate is pointless, since onResume is always called after onCreate anyway. Hence if I understand correctly, the call in onCreate serves no useful purpose and can be safely removed.

Could someone please either confirm these points, or let me know what I have misunderstood.

Olly

Comment: Also, isn't the onResume method completely pointless in this example? According to the life-cycle docs a paused Activity retains all of its state, so what's the point in repopulating the fields when it is unpaused (given that they cannot be changed elsewhere)?

Comment: Well a very common pattern is to present a listview, when a row is clicked a new activity is opened to allow editing of the item that was clicked.  When that happens, you'll want to refresh the data during onResume so that the listview reflects those changes.  At first glance of that example it looks like they are in fact retrieving data from the database that may have been modified.  It's more likely that they don't need to call populateFields() in the onCreate but they do need to leave it in onresume.

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to put a populateFields() call in onCreate and not in onResume? There is no situation (as far as I can tell) where the underlying data can change when this Activity is paused, therefore it should be unnecessary to load it each time the activity is unpaused?

Comment: Yes, if you are correct that the data won't be changed while this activity is paused, then onCreate should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand...

You are correct that onResume is always called eventually after onCreate, and you can often put the code there.  Keep in mind though that onResume will also be called when an activity comes back to the foreground, without first going through onCreate.  So for one time initialization code (like setContentView() or initializing variables) the onCreate event is a better place.

Also, you are correct about the onPause and onStop.  onPause is where you'd normally code the state handling.  onPause is killable so that onStop can potentially not even get called in very low memory situations.

Comment: Oops I just noticed you were referring to onSaveInstanceState not onStop (not sure how I got off track there, sorry).  Their example is correct.  While savestate will get called twice at times, they need to call it in onSaveInstanceState to get the ID of the new data to add to the bundle and in onPause (in the case that onSaveInstanceState isn't called) just to make sure the data is at least saved.

Comment: Ah - Ignore my previous post here..talking rubbish :). Thanks.

Comment: saveState called by onSaveInstanceState modifies mRowId, which is then put in the bundle by the next line in onSaveInstanceState.  While that rowid is technically persistent in that it's in the database, the way they are using it there, it isn't.  There they are using it to know which note is being displayed.  However, that is why they do also call saveState in the onPause event.  At that point they aren't concerned with which ID is being displayed, but that the data is saved and not lost.   Since onSaveInstanceState may not be called, they have to call it from onPause as well.